# how to prevent loop when hooking keydown event?

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

i hope to hook keyboard but if i hooked it,

when i press down and hold it,

it always call until i release it

but i'm just want call it one time like keyup

what should i do?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT pKey = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;
        int key = pKey->vkCode;
        cout << key << endl;

    }
    if (wParam == WM_KEYUP)
    {
        PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT pKey = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;
        int key = pKey->vkCode;
        cout << key << endl;
    }
    CallNextHookEx(hKBHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    return 0;
}

int _tmain() {
    HMODULE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    hKBHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardProc, hInstance, NULL);

    MSG Msg;

    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0)) { DispatchMessage(&Msg); }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use a boolean variable to control if you already had pressed your button or not

Comment: That is how the keyboard controller behaves, you can't teach it new tricks with a hook.  Nothing you can't fix with a bool[256] to track whether you saw the WM_KEYDOWN but not yet the WM_KEYUP.

Comment: @HansPassant: You don't need that, the system tracks state for you.  [Check bit 30 of `lParam`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx) that comes with `WM_KEYDOWN`, which appears  to be a group of bits that are in `flags` of the `KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT`

Comment: If you solved it then it's OK for you to answer your own question.

Comment: @BenVoigt: The [WM_KEYDOWN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280.aspx) message flags do not appear to be passed through to the [KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644967.aspx) flags field.

Comment: @IInspectable: WM_KEYDOWN lParam bits 24-31 line up exactly with KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT `flags` field, bits 0-7.  (Bits 16-23 are transferred to the `scancode` field)

Comment: @BenVoigt: Maybe. The documentation doesn't point that out, though. Especially bit 6 (which presumably maps to bit 30 in the `WM_KEYDOWN`'s lParam) is marked as *"Reserved"*, with no contractual guarantees.